# Spring Batch JDBC reader mark as read

Tags: jdbc, transactions, spring-batch

I am looking for a nice way to export from a JDBC datasource in spring batch into a csv file the upload to an FTP and mark the rows as exported from the read table (a column exportdate exists).

I cannot find a transactional way to do it so that we actually mark the line as exported only if the file upload is successful.

Comment: I was thinking of using CompositeItemWriter and update the column with a specific writer and use a transaction manager... But all of this seems very complicated and I am sure there is a better way...

Comment: When should a record be marked as exported? When it's written to the CSV file or when the CSV file is uploaded to the FTP server?

Comment: when it's uploaded to the FTP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a 2 step job.
*First step:* standard read (from JDCB), process (transform record from CSV entry) and regular write (using a FlatFileItemWriter).
*Second step:* upload file to FTP using Spring integration.

About column `exportdate` you can achive the goal to update the column from a `ItemWriteListener.afterWrite` because it is

> called after ItemWriter.write(java.util.List). This will be called
>   **before any transaction is committed**, and before
>   ChunkListener.afterChunk(ChunkContext)

I hope this can help